# JQuery .not() Selection Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, opacity

Below, I have pasted a link to my JQuery enabled webpage. Looking at the source code, you can see I used

`$('html').not(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.25);`

trying to make the whole screen fade except for a clicked DIV. Unfortunately, whenever I test this out, I find that everything is faded, including the DIV that is supposedly unselected in the above command. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Feel Free to view the source code at:
http://numberonekits.com/SchoolWeb/index.html
The CSS and other JS files are in the same directory.

Below is the relevant code:

```
<body>
//other stuff that should be faded...
<div id="templatemo_content_wrapper">
//other stuff that should be faded...
<div id="templatemo_sidebar">
//other stuff that should be faded...
<div id="announce">

<p>This is the DIV that shouldn't be faded</p>

</div>
//other stuff that should be faded...
</div>
//other stuff that should be faded...
</div>
//other stuff that should be faded...
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as `this` is not the `html` element, you will be fading the `html` element, which will fade all of its descendants.

I haven't look at your source, but it sounds like you have a group of siblings.

If so, you need to select them, and do `.not(this)` on that selection.

Something like:

```
var sections = $('.top_sections');

// then on some event
sections.click( function() {
    sections.not( this ).fadeTo('fast', 0.25);
});
```

---

*Posting alternate solution from comment below:*

Since the element you want to highlight is nested inside ancestors whose other descendants you want to obscure, you should...

...Take a different approach. Use layers.

Have a `div` that covers the width and height of the entire page. Let's call it `blocker`. Place it at `z-index:100` or something. Make it `background:#FFF` and `opacity:0`.

Then when you want to highlight the `announce` section, set its `z-index` to something higher than `100` (or higher than the `z-index` of the `blocker`), and then fade in the `blocker` to `opacity .75`.

Comment: What do you mean by '.top_sections'? Does this class refer to the elements directly above `this` in the DOM hierarchy?

Comment: @user788532: It means that I assume your HTML is divided up into a group of elements toward the top of the structure, and you want to fade all but one of them. You didn't provide any code in your question that would give me a clue as to where I should be looking in your HTML. If you want an answer specific to your code, you need to provide your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is very difficult to provide all the code of a webpage in a stackoverflow question; this is why I provided a link to the webpage with the code I am asking about.

Comment: @user788532: People usually provide a minimal working example.

Comment: @user788532: Take a different approach. Use layers. Have a `div` that covers the width and height of the entire page. Let's call it `blocker`. Place it at `z-index:100` or something. Make it `background:#FFF` and `opacity:0`. Then when you want to highlight the `announce` section, set its `z-index` to something higher than `100` (or higher than the z-index of the `blocker`), and then fade in the `blocker` to opacity `.75`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').children().not('#templatemo_content_wrapper').add(
  $('#templatemo_content_wrapper').children().not(this)
).fadeTo('fast', 0.25);
```

may do the trick.

Comment: You get the idea, you must use `not(this)` only at the right level, `not`ting containers in the way there. I only looked briefly on your page source, so maybe the real sequence must be deeper...

Comment: the issue is that parts of my page are not included in any elements except <body> itself. Therefore, if I don't fade the <body>, there will be parts of the page unfaded